# WPF convert image to text

Tags: wpf

I have an WPF application. there is a process where the user does the data entry. Now due to too many human error in entering the data, I'm thinking to have the paper scanned and the WPF read it to capture the text. How can I go about this? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in WPF itself (that I am aware) of that would do this.  WPF is about the Presentation of data.  The stuff that you want to do would be done in an underlying library.

There are third party libraries (with SDKs) that you can use, and Office apparently has some of this capability as well.  Just Google [C# optical character recognition](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=c%23+optical+character+recognition&aq=f&aqi=g1g-o1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=53894057c0dc71cc) and find something that fits your needs.

Comment: hi.. been trying this sample from here: http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/. But it is giving error exit code with one on Init line.. I got suggestions from here: http://markmail.org/message/4vrkih6p446w3lwt#query:+page:1+mid:4vrkih6p446w3lwt+state:results. I checked that the tessdata folder does exist and contains the 8 files.. can you help please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know any more about it.  Perhaps if you repost your comment as a new question with specific details, you will get somebody that knows more about it.